# Select setTimeout attribute from ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm sending some data to page.php with ajax, in response (whole html page) there is success message and script tag with setTimeout function:

```
setTimeout("window.location.href = '/new_ID' ", 2000)
```

I want to select only `/new_ID` part so I can make redirect instantly.
I can select whole `script` tag with `.find()` function but don't know how to select only href part (don't want to use `.split()`, but is there any other solution?).

Thanks!

Comment: after .find(), add .match('/href='([^']+)/)[1] to get the value under quotes using regex.

Answer (score 0):

After .find(), add .match('/href='([^']+)/)[1] to get the value under quotes using regex.

```
.find("script").match("/href='([^']+)/")[1];
```

Comment: This regex isn't working for me, syntax error. I solved that with `.text().split("'")[1]` -_- Thanks anyway

Comment: Forgot a " there.